# Normal Map Breaking Glass Material in Cycles again?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normal-map, glass

I faced this problem when the normal map breaks the glass material messing the whole reflections up. For what I have been reading this was fixed long ago so I guess I am doing something wrong but I dont get to see what it is.

Using Cycles in Blender 3.0 in Windows 10.

Glass Material working well with no Normal map.
[image]

Refractions get messed up after adding the normal map.
[image]

You can download the Blender file from here if that helps:
https://we.tl/t-imDWLkh2JW

Comment: The Normal Map Image Texture should have the _Color-Space_ set to _Non-Color_ (you currently have it set to _sRGB_).

Comment: There you go. That was it. 

Thanks so that. I know I was missing out just in the basics. 

Thank you!

Comment: Although Christopher is right ... there is zero pixel difference in your screens ...